# multiple functions returning error of object not found

Tags: r

I am trying to create three functions embedded in one another, but keep getting an error of object not found. the first function `f` is the main function, the second one `g` output w,y and z and the last function `k` uses the result of the second function to compute r. but I keep getting an object not found error, please is there a better way of restructuring the code below to eliminate the error?

```
    f <- function(alfa,e1,e2,n1,n2,t){
    n <- n1+n2
    N <- sum(n)
    t <- n/N
    a <- e1
    b <- n1 - e1
    c <- e2
    d <- n2 - e2
    #---- function 1
    g <- function(a,c,w,v,z){
    v <- (1/a) + (1/c) - (1/n1)- (1/n2)
    y <- (a/n1)/(c/n2)
    w <- 1/v
    cum_w <- cumsum(w)
    var_peff <- 1/cum_w
    se <- sqrt(var_peff)
    cum_s2 <- cumsum(s2)
    lgy <- log((a/n1)/(c/n2))
    s2 <- w*lgy
    p.eff <- cum_s2/cum_w
    z <- abs(p.eff/se)
    }
    #---- function 2
    h <- function(za,pe){
    pe <- 2*(1 - pnorm(qnorm(1-(alfa/2))/sqrt(t)))
    za <- qnorm(1 - pe)
    }
    #----- function 3
    k <- function(za,pe){
    r <- za/pe
    }
    ans <- list(t=t, y=y, v=v, w=w, zup=za)
    return(data.frame(ans))
    }
    f(alfa = 0.05, e1 = c(3,9,12,34,77), e2 = c(12,26,25,66,130), n1 = 
    c(18,33,85,162,481), n2 = c(18,40,97,146,489))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and [mcve]! Please make your code reproducible by giving some data. Show us how you are calling your function `f()`. So, edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52116873/edit

Comment: You don't call any of your three interior functions so they don't do anything (you also need them to return something, right now even if you would call them nothing would happen). So when you create the list in the end, object v, w and za simply don't exist. Other comments: why first create ans as a list to then make it a data frame? Why calculate a bunch of variables that you don't seem to use?

Comment: @Wave, I created the ans as a list and then data frame to have the output orderly arranged in a table. the bunch of variables is used in computation of the required variable

Comment: @李哲源, what do you mean by calling them? I think that is the problem I am having. I want those functions to remain because the code here is for illustration, you can imagine having a thousand line of code, debugging might really be a serious pain in the butt. so by having them in functions one will be able to trace the source of the problem

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I noticed

First and foremost: If a variable is created within a function(), it is only available in that function's hidden environment. It is not available in the global environment, and also not available within other functions.

In function `g()`, you create `y <- (a/n1)/(c/n2)`. But `y` is not created in your global environment.
Later, you try to call `y` in function `f()` with: `ans <- list(t=t, y=y, v=v, w=w, zup=za)`

In order to use `y`, you should either assign a value to it inside the function where you call it, or in the global environment.
This can be achieved by running part of your code directly, instead or calling it from within a function, or by writing a function where you create these values and assign them (for example:

```
za <- function(pe) {
    za <- qnorm(1 - pe)
    return(za)
}
```

Another thing is that in creating a function `fun <- function(x,y,z) {}`, the `x`,`y`, and `z` are inputs for that function. It seems that you wrote down some of the variables that are created within the function. This will result in (even more) errors, since R expects than all requested parameters for a function are specified. In other words, function `fun <- function(x,y,z) {do something}` required a command like: `fun(x=10, y='something', z=100)`

Another thing I noticed is that your function `f()` requires a parameter named `t`. When calling `f(alfa = 0.05, e1 = c(3,9,12,34,77), e2 = c(12,26,25,66,130), n1 = 
    c(18,33,85,162,481), n2 = c(18,40,97,146,489))`, you are not specifying `t={value}`. This will result in an error, when the abovementioned error is solved

EDIT: After your request to restructure the functions I took a closer look and realised that the sub-function in your code are actually abundant. Everything can be done in one function. All I did below is to remove the function calls, but keep the content of the function and reordered one or two commands so they were created before needed.
The result:

```
f <- function(alfa,e1,e2,n1,n2,t){
  n <- n1+n2
  N <- sum(n)
  t <- n/N
  a <- e1
  b <- n1 - e1
  c <- e2
  d <- n2 - e2

    v <- (1/a) + (1/c) - (1/n1)- (1/n2)
    y <- (a/n1)/(c/n2)
    w <- 1/v
    cum_w <- cumsum(w)
    var_peff <- 1/cum_w
    se <- sqrt(var_peff)
    lgy <- log((a/n1)/(c/n2))
    s2 <- w*lgy

    cum_s2 <- cumsum(s2)

    p.eff <- cum_s2/cum_w
    z <- abs(p.eff/se)

    pe <- 2*(1 - pnorm(qnorm(1-(alfa/2))/sqrt(t)))
    za <- qnorm(1 - pe)

    r <- za/pe
  ans <- list(t=t, y=y, v=v, w=w, zup=za)
  return(data.frame(ans))
}

 f(alfa = 0.05, e1 = c(3,9,12,34,77), e2 = c(12,26,25,66,130), n1 = 
    c(18,33,85,162,481), n2 = c(18,40,97,146,489))
```

Output:

```
           t         y          v         w      zup
1 0.02294455 0.2500000 0.30555556  3.272727      Inf
2 0.04652645 0.4195804 0.09426962 10.607871      Inf
3 0.11599745 0.5477647 0.10125935  9.875631 5.636466
4 0.19630338 0.4642724 0.03154113 31.704639 4.271615
5 0.61822817 0.6021590 0.01655533 60.403512 2.235971
```

Comment: thanks, I will appreciate if you can use the code to illustrate the restructuring you suggested, for clarity sake. The `t` can either be provided by the user or calculated from the data that was why it was never assigned a value from the calling `f(alfa = 0.05, e1 = c(3,9,12,34,77), e2 = c(12,26,25,66,130), n1 = 
    c(18,33,85,162,481), n2 = c(18,40,97,146,489))`

Comment: thanks, I already have it in a single function and it worked just looking for a way to break them down into different functions because the code is lengthy ( over 1000 line of codes) and debugging is really stressing me out

Comment: Restructuring code into multiple functions depends on personal preference a lot. In general I would recommend doing so if you need multiple lines of code to calculate just one value. But make sure all required values are passed on to the function and that you don't need any other values that are created on the way. Also, I would suggest defining functions elsewhere, and not within other functions. You could even make a separate file with the function and load it using source("my_function.R"). You can then use it as you normally would

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, I really appreciate.